# How can I echo out the users dropdown selection?

Tags: php, html, select, post, menu

I'm trying to echo to the screen what a user selects from a dropdown menu. So whenever the user selects a number, it updates the text below it in to display what they selected. Here's my code below:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<label for="numbers"></label>
<form action="drop.php">
    <select name="numbers">
    <option value="0">select number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['numbers']))
{
    $numbers = $_POST['numbers'];
    $error = "?";
    echo "<p>" . $numbers . "</p>";
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

UPDATED MAIN CODE

Comment: This would be better suited for javascript.  You are currently missing a `<form>` tags and you don't need a submit button but unless you want to add javascript `onchange` to submit your form you should include one.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the info. I'll keep the JS in mind, but maintaining PHP for this, I've added a form that has action="file.php", and I've included the submit button after the </select> but inside the form. It still doesn't seem to be working. Updated code is in the main body, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest reading PHP's [Dealing with Forms](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) tutorial and also researching the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

For your code example, I've added a [form element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form) along with an "onchange" attribute to the select element which will automatically submit the form when a number is chosen.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="<?php echo basename(__FILE__); ?>" method="post">
<label for="numbers">Numbers:</label>
<select name="numbers" onchange="document.forms[0].submit();">
    <option value="0">select number</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php

if (array_key_exists('numbers', $_POST)) {
    $numbers = $_POST['numbers'];
    echo '<p>' . $numbers . '</p>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was needing, thank you for the information and for the links. I'll definitely read through those and start figuring this out. have a nice day

Answer (score 2):

Try method="post" on form declaration. or use $_GET instead of $_POST ON drop.php

if(isset($_POST['numbers']))

Answer (score 1):

Add method="post" to the form

```
<form action="drop.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't realize this!